# Creating hyperlinks in wysiwyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg

I installed the tinymce wysiwyg editor and it converts hyperlinks into [url= tags.
How do I convert this to html i.e. `<a href="`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your formats, there is no `<a>` allowed? You can find it under /admin/config/content/formats
Or you checked that HTML will be rendered as text.

Comment: Hi, it looks like the tinymce editor is using markup instead of html. The output is [url=http://www.somlink.co.uk]link[/url]
and not
<a href="http://www.somlink.co.uk">link</a>
There is no setting in the fomats to change this.

Comment: I think you need to check your Wysiwyg profiles and grant enough rights in /admin/settings/wysiwyg.

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE is most likely not the source of the problem. There's something not ok with your Input filters. Try to create a new set with no filtering at all. Rhis should fix the problem. If you  need some of your filters, switch them on one by one to find the one causing the problem.